# Facing an issue after test stand alone apk but in development all is good

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have a weird problem with my project which is an appointment booking app, but it happen only after I test the apk on device and before that (I mean on development) everything is working without problem
and the problem I facing after the build is when user book an appointment after successful pay it will book exactly 3 times (same appointment) on my firebase real-time database no matter what. (I have to mention that in development all is good and it book just one time as the user ask for one appointment). and because of this happening after build I don't know how to debug it or where the problem is. I'm gonna paste the code which handle the booking part.

```
const bookingHandler = () => {
    Linking.openURL('http://www.medicalbookingapp.cloudsite.ir/sendPay.php');
  }

  const handler = (e) => handleOpenUrl(e.url);
  useEffect(() => {

    Linking.addEventListener('url', handler)

    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handler);

    }

  });

  const handleOpenUrl = useCallback((url) => {
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\/\w*:\w*\/\W/g, '') // exp://.... --> ''
    const id = route.split('=')[1]

    if (id == 1) {
      handleDispatch();
      toggleModal();
    } else if (id == 0) {
      console.log('purchase failed...');
      toggleModal();
    }
  });

  const handleDispatch = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(
      BookingActions.addBooking(
        therapistId,
        therapistFirstName,
        therapistLastName,
        selected.title,
        moment(selectedDate).format("YYYY-MMM-DD"),
        selected.slots,
      )
    );

    dispatch(
      doctorActions.updateTherapists(therapistId, selected.slots, selectedDate, selected.title, selectedPlanIndex, selectedTimeIndex)
    );
    setBookingConfirm(true)
  })
```

my action:

```
export const addBooking = (therapistId, therapistFirstName, therapistLastName, sessionTime, sessionDate, slotTaken) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    
    const confirmDate = moment(new Date()).format("ddd DD MMMM YYYY")

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://mymedicalbooking.firebaseio.com/bookings/${userId}.json`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId,
          therapistId,
          confirmDate,
          therapistFirstName,
          therapistLastName,
          sessionTime,
          sessionDate,
          slotTaken
        })
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
   
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_BOOKING,
      bookingData: {
        userId: userId,
        therapistId: therapistId,
        therapistFirstName: therapistFirstName,
        therapistLastName: therapistLastName,
        sessionTime: sessionTime,
        sessionDate: sessionDate
      }
    });
  };
};
```

my reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  bookings: [],
  userBookings: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BOOKING:
      const newBooking = new Booking(
        action.bookingData.id,
        action.bookingData.therapistId,
        action.bookingData.therapistFirstName,
        action.bookingData.therapistLastName,
        action.bookingData.bookingdate
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        bookings: state.bookings.concat(newBooking)
      };
    case FETCH_BOOKING:
      const userBookings = action.userBookings;
      return {
        ...state,
        userBookings: userBookings
      };
  }

  return state;
};
```

I really need to solve this if you have any idea or any suggestion for debugging or even my code has any problem please let me know.
I greatly appreciated.